# Issue with Navigation component and TextInputLayout error

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using the `Navigation` component in my app to create an on boarding flow. The intro `Fragment` needs to have a transparent `status bar` so that the background image covers all of the screen while the sign in `fragment` will have a visible `status bar`. The host `activity` i use has the `android:fitsSystemWindows` set to `false` as well as the intro fragment, while the rest have it to `true`. In the sign in screen i have 2 `TextInputLayout` in which i want to show an error message. This is the weird part when having the `android:fitsSystemWindows` of the parent set to false, the `TextInputLayout` error message is not showing, while if i change it to true it will. Though i need to keep it false not to break my intro UI.

Do you have any suggestions of how to fix this issue and if i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to change the status bar color (with styles) within each Fragment, by using something like:

`getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_color));`